# Simple integral inequality question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Sorry for easy question, I am not so good at analysis.

If assume $\int_{A} f d\mu \leq \int_{A} g d\mu$ $\forall A\in\Sigma$,

Can I show $f\leq g$ almost everywhere?

I know that $\int_{A}f d\mu = $ $\sup\{∫g:\text{g simple and } g≤f\}$ but maybe I don't understand the definiton and the answer dircetly follows the definition

Comment: Do you mean for *all* $A \in \Sigma$, or just one $A \in \Sigma$?  I assume the former, because the latter statement would make your conclusion pretty obviously false.

Comment: yes, i mean that. i will update the question. thank you

Comment: What is $\Sigma$?

Comment: it is not specified in the question. just that $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ is measure space with sigma-finite $\mu$

Comment: Ok, so it's a sigma-algebra.

Comment: yes. am i right to think the answer follows from the definition, or is it more involved?

Comment: I depends on what it means for you to follow from the definition :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $A=\{ x \in X: f(x)>g(x) \}$. We have $A\in \Sigma$ (why?). The statement $f\leq g$ a.e. is equivalent to $\mu(A)=0$.

Define

$$ A_n=\{ x\in X : f(x)-g(x) \geq \frac{1}{n} \}.$$

We have 
$$A_n\subseteq A_{n+1} \quad \text{ and } \quad A= \bigcup_{n\geq 1} A_n.$$

Thus we have

$$ \mu(A)= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(A_n).$$

Use your integral inequality to show $\mu(A_n)=0$ and deduce $\mu(A)=0$.

Edit: On can use the integral inequality in the following way. We have

$$ 0\leq \frac{1}{n} \mu(A_n)  \leq \int_{A_n} f-g d\mu \leq 0.$$

Hence,

$$ \frac{1}{n} \mu(A_n)=0.$$

This implies $\mu(A_n)=0$.

Comment: How to use the inequaliity to show $\mu(A_{n}) = 0$ when $A_{n}$ is a set, not a function that I can integrate?

Comment: @ArsalanDashti Is it clear now?

Comment: yes, thank you very much

Comment: @ArsalanDashti You're welcome. If you think that your question is answered by my post, you can accept my answer.